# How to group and merge mutil cell in one string without for loop?

Tags: sql-server, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

[The table looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aFfei.png)

I have a table something like this, how can I merge each id's dtl_details to one string and order by seq, the output should be like this:

```
id | dtl_details  
123 | rm 123, 11/F, 123 abc st, CWB, HK  
222 | rm 234, 23/F, 111 dllm st, MK, KLN
```

Which method would be faster (using SQL query or Python with Pandas) because in the real table, there are around 4,000,000 rows of data.

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: FYI - databases don't have cells, thats a spreadsheet concept. And the best way to find out which is fastest is to try it. However if it can be done in a query then that is often faster than pulling all the data to your app.

Comment: sorry about that I am just think if there have image would be more easy to know what I am talking about, and I tried use for loop to handle this question but it is slow, that why I am finding another method to fix this problem.

Comment: Presenting data as tabular text is much clearer than an image. The solution John shows below is quite easy to find with your favourite search engine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SQL Server, `string_agg()` should do the trick

```
Select ID
      ,dtl_details = string_agg(dtl_details ,',') within group (order by seq)
 From  YourTable 
 Group By ID
```